# How to select spesific list from nested lists with python

Tags: python

Hello guys I have list like A

```
max_x=4

min_x=0

A=[[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)], [(0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2)]]
```

A, includes different group of points (x,y) format.I wanted to find group if includes my max and min same time.Output should be like B.Because this cluster includes 0 and 4 as x.

```
B= [(0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2)]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. My advice is to try to break the problem down into smaller parts. For example, if you had a single list from A, could you write code that tells you whether it meets the condition? If that's too hard, break it down again - consider one of the tuples, like `(0, 3)`. Can you write code to tell if includes the max X value? Now, think about how to repeat that test, and check whether *any* of the tuples meets the condition. Then use that code with the `max_x` and `min_x` values, to see if *both* are found. Then use *that* code to test each `A` value separately.

Comment: Each of those broken-down steps offers you a separate question, and a separate place to learn technique for solving problems. As a side note: this question clearly doesn't have anything to do with Numpy, so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to find any sublists of `A` that have a tuple that has `x == min_x` and also a tuple that has `x == max_x`:

```py
max_x=4
min_x=0
A=[[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)], [(0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2)]]

B = [l for l in A if any(x == min_x for x,_ in l) and any(x == max_x for x,_ in l)]
```

Output:

```
[[(0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2)]]
```

Comment: when I use this code for my A it prints same as A. My output not seems like B.Thank you.

Comment: I'm using the same data as in your question and I get the result I show in the answer. See for example https://ideone.com/ZdA44i

Comment: Could it be that, for the actual `A`, every element *actually does* meet the condition?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel assuming the code from the answer, that would seem to be the only solution